# What image compression algorithm does React Native Image Picker use?

Tags: android, react-native, image-compression

**What I am trying to find out:**

Which image compression algorithm does [React Native Image Picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker) use (especially for jpg)?

---

**Background:**

I'm working on a React Native app that will be used to gather images for machine-learning research.

The app is built with React Native and the module used for launching the camera / taking the pictures is [React Native Image Picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker).

More specifically, I am using this method: `launchCamera(options?, callback);` to which I am passing the `options` object like this:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'

(...)

var options = {
  mediaType: 'photo',
  quality: 0.5
}

ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, res => {
  (...)
}
```

Unfortunately, the only piece of information that I could find on the internet about the quality parameter is this table on their Git page:
[image]
which is obviously insufficient.

**Note:** My guess is that [Bitmap.CompressFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat) is ultimately used, but again, I can't find anything about the compression process on the original documentation (and couldn't find any relevant information on other websites).

**Note 2:** I know that an ideal dataset should contain images with the best possible resolution but I am forced to compress the images. That's the caveat, the internet connection of those who will upload the images might be bad. Leaving them uncompressed makes uploading unfeasible.

Summarising, it is very important for our research team to understand which compression algorithm is used so that it's taken into account while training the [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) model. So, what does React Native Image Picker do with the quality parameter?

Comment: why do you think is uses some non-standard algorithm and not the ones used in [standard image formats like jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression)?

Comment: It might be using a DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform) based algorithm or might not. I need to be sure about it as it might affect the entire outcome of the project.